# Одного ли корня слова "скальп" и "скульптор"?

Tags: этимология

Случайно ли созвучие слов "скальп" и "скульптор"?

Answer (score 2):

Да, у них один корень, потому и созвучие не случайно.
Sculpere (лат.) — «высекать, вырезать». Скульптор - резчик, ваятель. Скальп (англ. scalp от лат. scalpere — резать) — кожа головы с волосами, снятая с убитого врага, использовался в качестве трофея( википедия). Отсюда же и скальпель - медицинский инструмент для разрезания. В русском языке есть лексемы "скоблить", "скубить" схожие по семантике и звучанию с латинскими. [image: на фото выдержка из словаря Преображенского А. Г.]

Comment: Странно. У вас не вызвало подозрение отсутствие ссылки по этимологии СКАЛЬП в википедии? Просмотрел несколько англоязычных источников - scalp (oxford, m-webster, etymonline) - везде указано, что есть скандинавская версия (и она не подтверждена окончательно). Но https://www.etymonline.com/word/scalp#etymonline_v_22831 говорит, что все это может восходит к PIE (proto-indo-Europ.) - to cut - резать, тогда формально родство есть. Но, получается, без участия латыни.

Comment: Стр. 301 взята из словаря А.Г. Преображенского?

Comment: Да, из этимологического словаря А. Г. ПРЕОБРАЖЕНСКОГО, ТОМ 2.